# CVAT Installation on Kubernetes

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, supervisord

Using v0.5.1 from the GitHub repo (https://github.com/opencv/cvat), I've pulled it down locally, built and tagged it, and pushed it up to a local docker registry.

When I try to deploy it on a kubernetes instance from the registry I get the following error in the pod logs:

> Error: Format string '%(ENV_HOME)s/wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -t 0 -- bash -ic \\n"/usr/bin/python3 ~/manage.py migrate && \\n/usr/bin/python3 ~/manage.py collectstatic --no-input && \\nexec /usr/bin/python3 $HOME/manage.py runmodwsgi --log-to-terminal --port 8080 \\n--limit-request-body 1073741824 --log-level INFO --include-file ~/mod_wsgi.conf \\n%(ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS)s --locale %(ENV_LC_ALL)s"' for 'program:runserver.command' contains names ('ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS') which cannot be expanded. Available names: ENV_CUDA_SUPPORT, ENV_CVAT_PORT, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8080_TCP, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8443_TCP, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8443_TCP_ADDR, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8443_TCP_PORT, ENV_CVAT_PORT_8443_TCP_PROTO, ENV_CVAT_SERVICE_HOST, ENV_CVAT_SERVICE_PORT, ENV_CVAT_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP, ENV_CVAT_SERVICE_PORT_8443_TCP, ENV_DB2_PORT, ENV_DB2_PORT_50000_TCP, ENV_DB2_PORT_50000_TCP_ADDR, ENV_DB2_PORT_50000_TCP_PORT, ENV_DB2_PORT_50000_TCP_PROTO, ENV_DB2_PORT_55000_TCP, ENV_DB2_PORT_55000_TCP_ADDR, ENV_DB2_PORT_55000_TCP_PORT, ENV_DB2_PORT_55000_TCP_PROTO, ENV_DB2_PORT_60006_TCP, ENV_DB2_PORT_60006_TCP_ADDR, ENV_DB2_PORT_60006_TCP_PORT, ENV_DB2_PORT_60006_TCP_PROTO, ENV_DB2_PORT_60007_TCP, ENV_DB2_PORT_60007_TCP_ADDR, ENV_DB2_PORT_60007_TCP_PORT, ENV_DB2_PORT_60007_TCP_PROTO, ENV_DB2_SERVICE_HOST, ENV_DB2_SERVICE_PORT, ENV_DB2_SERVICE_PORT_50000_TCP, ENV_DB2_SERVICE_PORT_55000_TCP, ENV_DB2_SERVICE_PORT_60006_TCP, ENV_DB2_SERVICE_PORT_60007_TCP, ENV_DEXTR_MODEL_DIR, ENV_DJANGO_CONFIGURATION, ENV_HOME, ENV_HOSTNAME, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP_ADDR, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP_PORT, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_TCP_PROTO, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP_ADDR, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP_PORT, ENV_KUBERNETES_PORT_53_UDP_PROTO, ENV_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST, ENV_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT, ENV_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_DNS, ENV_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_DNS_TCP, ENV_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS, ENV_LANG, ENV_LC_ALL, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8080_TCP, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8443_TCP, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8443_TCP_ADDR, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8443_TCP_PORT, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_PORT_8443_TCP_PROTO, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_SERVICE_HOST, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_SERVICE_PORT, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP, ENV_NGINX_REVERSEPROXY_SERVICE_PORT_8443_TCP, ENV_OPENVINO_TOOLKIT, ENV_PATH, ENV_REID_MODEL_DIR, ENV_TERM, ENV_TEST_UI_PORT, ENV_TEST_UI_PORT_8080_TCP, ENV_TEST_UI_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR, ENV_TEST_UI_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT, ENV_TEST_UI_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO, ENV_TEST_UI_SERVICE_HOST, ENV_TEST_UI_SERVICE_PORT, ENV_TEST_UI_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP, ENV_TF_ANNOTATION, ENV_TF_ANNOTATION_MODEL_PATH, ENV_TZ, ENV_USER, ENV_WITH_DEXTR, ENV_http_proxy, ENV_https_proxy, ENV_no_proxy, ENV_socks_proxy, group_name, here, host_node_name, process_num, program_name in section 'program:runserver' (file: 'supervisord.conf')
>
> For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h

I can however run it locally with no issues.

Any insight is gratefully recieved.

Comment: If this isn’t your own application, I’d suggest contacting the application author, perhaps by filing a GitHub issue.  If it is, can you add enough detail to the question so that others can help; for instance, whatever bit of code is trying to invoke `wait-for-it.sh`?

Comment: @DavidMaze, the application authors in their GitHub repo suggested popping a question on here as a means to get assistance.

Comment: You might read through [ask] and restate the question.  Generally good SO questions include the actual source code and user actions needed to reproduce the issue, as text in the question (not an external GitHub link).

Answer (score 0):

I have used kompose to convert the docker-compose into helm chart, and successfully installed cvat on kubernetes. Although having some minor issue in finding out the entry port of the cvat web.